# SMS client URL preview detection

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web

I have a situation recently identified by the users of my app which i did more than 2 years ago.

To cut the matter short there is a URL link sent to the customer on click of which some things executes based upon the encrypted key that is passed along with the URL query string. Earlier it was working fine because the user had to click on the link in the SMS to execute that. But now a days the SMS clients for example in iPhone or something similar they pick up the URL and try to show the preview (similar to what what's app skype etc do). But the problem is that the link is only one time and on a second click the link is already expired because it is assumed that its already hit.

So, in this situation the user is never able to go to the next step since the link is already consumed in the form of the message preview.

I have a work around for the same for example to show a fake page or something similar but i do not want to use that since i understand that this think i quite common and you genius folks out there have something to share.

Please share how to may be identify the client which are just looking for og tags or how to identify these kinds of clients so that the actual request is not processed unless is done manually by the user by clicking on the link.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no consistent user agent clients have to use in the open graph spec.

Therefore blocking based on that is an ever moving target, each app could use a different agent if they so wish.

The way I have always countered to this is that a get action should never be a destructive action.
The get should always be safe to run over and over.
If you need a destructive action, the page should include some form of user input/button/link which would trigger a post to the server.

If required you can then also add an added level of security in the link by asking the user to confirm something from the data, e.g. their phone number.

This means if a link was to get into the wrong hands (remember, SMS are not encrypted so can be snooped) then without this information the user is required to enter they will be unable to execute the destructive action of the link.